# Redirection to a page with parameters in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4 for making user profile.
in view

```
<li><a href="users">Users</a></li>
<li><a href="userDetail/1">User Details</a></li>
```

in my route

```
Route::get('/admin/users','AdminController@showUsersPage')->before('auth');
Route::get('admin/userDetail/{id}','AdminController@userDetail')->before('auth');
```

my controller is

```
public function showUsersPage(){
        $userlist =DB::table('userdetails')->get(); 
        return View::make('admin/userlist')->with('userlist', $userlist);
    }

public function userDetail($id){

        $userDetail =DB::table('userdetails')
                        ->where('userdetails.id',$id)
                        ->get();    
        return View::make('admin/userdetail')->with('userDetail',$userDetail);
    }
```

my problem is when i first click on user link it goes to user list page(url is http://localhost/vishal/site/public/admin/users)
and on clicking user detail link it is goes to user detail page url is changing (http://localhost/vishal/site/public/admin/userDetail/1).and if again click on user link the url shows as http://localhost/vishal/site/public/admin/userDetail/users actually i want as http://localhost/vishal/site/public/admin/users
how can i solve the issue.?

Comment: finally i got solved the issue.
changed view as 
  <a href="{{url('admin/users')}}">users</a>

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got solved the issue. changed view as users